# Lookup image conditionally in SharePoint list formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a column named `LinkType` that will tell if the item is a Bug, Requirement, Feature, etc and based on the value I would like to display different pictures. Previously I was using a similar setup with the `iconName` attribute, but for some reason it does not seem to work the same way with displaying images conditionally. What is wrong?

```
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
      "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
      "src": "=if([$LinkType] == 'Requirement', '/sites/aaa/publishingimages/requirement.gif', if([$LinkType] == 'Feature', '/sites/aaa/publishingimages/feature.gif', if([$LinkType] == 'Task', '/sites/aaa/publishingimages/task.gif', if([$LinkType] == 'Query', '/sites/aaa/publishingimages/query.gif', if([$LinkType] == 'Bug', '/sites/aaa/publishingimages/bug.gif', 'ErrorBadge'))))"
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any syntox error? I can see there is one `)` missing at the end of the expression in `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format snippet looks mostly fine and you should definitely be able to set an image's source conditionally. However, looks like you still have the `ErrorBadge` iconName value at the end. Without additional detail, it's hard to troubleshoot the exact problem you are experiencing. Try adding a `"debugMode":true"` to your format and opening the console to see if there are any helpful error messages.

In the meantime, it looks like you could simplify your format a bit to something like this:

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=@currentWeb + '/publishingimages/' + toLowerCase([$LinkType]) + '.gif'"
  }
}
```